# Compiler throws "Invalid initializer" when writing char const*

Tags: c, string, chars

I'm new to C programming so please help a fella out.
When compiling I'm getting a "invalid initializer" problem.This is the relevant code.

```
void lcd_writePString(char const* string) {
  char c;
  while ((c = (char)pgm_read_byte(string++)))
  lcd_writeChar(c);
}

void os_errorPStr(char const* str) {
  SREG &= 0b10111111; //Interrupts global deaktivieren
  lcd_clear();
  lcd_writePString(PSTR(str)); //THIS IS WHERE THE COMPILER THROWS OUT THE ERROR
  while (os_getInput()!=0b10000001){
    os_waitForInput();
  }
  lcd_clear();
  SREG |= 0b01000000;
 }
```

So why does my compiler throw out the error "invalid initializer"?
The PSTR thing writes the string onto the flash memory of my micro controller.

This is what PSTR does:

```
 /** \ingroup avr_pgmspace
     \def PSTR(s)

    Used to declare a static pointer to a string in program space. */
 # define PSTR(s) ((const PROGMEM char *)(s))
 #else  /* !DOXYGEN */
 /* The real thing. */
 # define PSTR(s) (__extension__({static const char __c[] PROGMEM = (s); &__c[0];}))
 #endif /* DOXYGEN */
```

Comment: Which libraries/hardware are you using? Those `lcd_*` and `PSTR()` functions aren't part of standard C, so you'll need to provide us with some more information.

Comment: What's `PSTR` ? We cannot answer this question without knowing that ?

Comment: Hey Andrew, the comment shows where the error is thrown. I added to my post what PSTR exaclty does =) Thank your for your efforts so far

Comment: My _guess_ is that `PSTR()` is telling the compiler how to store the string in memory as it compiles the code; as such, it possibly cannot be applied to a variable (`str` in your case).  Perhaps you need to use `PSTR()` in the call to `os_errorPStr()` instead of within it.  Either that or you cannot use it in a parameter (the "real thing" version appears to declare a variable) so you may need something like `char* tempstr = PSTR(str);` as the first line of `os_errorPStr()`?

Answer (score 0):

lcd_writePString expects a `char const*` yet you cast the parameter to `const PROGMEM char *` through some obscure macro. Either don't cast it to this type or change the prototype of lcd_writePString.

Comment: Well, I'm working on this at Uni at the macros are given. The instructions tell me to write something on the LCD with that exact command:  lcd_writePString(PSTR("Hello World")); So I think i have to do something with str prior to using it in that writePstring method

Comment: @zeldamania Then ask the person who wrote the instructions why they tell you to do something that causes a type conflict...